# Is there a way to turn on SageMaker model endpoints only when I am receiving inference requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a model endpoint which is InService and deployed on an ml.m4.xlarge instance. I am also using API Gateway to create a RESTful API.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to have my model endpoint only Inservice (or on standby) when I receive inference requests? Maybe by writing a lambda function or something that turns off the endpoint (so that it does not keep accumulating the per hour charges)
2. If q1 is possible, would this have some weird latency issues on the end users? Because it usually takes a couple of minutes for model endpoints to be created when I configure them for the first time.
3. If q1 is not possible, how would choosing a cheaper instance type affect the time it takes to perform inference (Say I'm only using the endpoints for an application that has a low number of users).

I am aware of this site that compares different instance types (https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/instance-types/)

But, does having a moderate network performance mean that the time to perform realtime inference may be longer?

Any recommendations are much appreciated. The goal is not to burn money when users are not requesting for predictions.

Answer (score 2):

How large is your model? If it is under the 50 MB size limit required by [AWS Lambda](https://dzone.com/articles/exploring-aws-lambda-deployment-limits) and the dependencies are small enough, there could be a way to rely directly on Lambda as an execution engine.

If your model is larger than 50 MB, there might *still* be a way to run it by storing it on EFS. See [EFS for Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to wait 5-10 minutes for SageMaker to launch, you can accomplish this by doing the following:

1. Set up a Lambda function (or create a method in an existing function) to check your endpoint status when the API is called. If the status != 'InService', call the function in #2.
2. Create another method that when called launches your endpoint and creates a metric alarm in Cloudwatch to monitor your primary lambda function's invocations. When the threshold falls below your desired invocations / period, it will call the function in #3.
3. Create a third method to delete your endpoint and the alarm when called. Technically, the alarm can't call a Lambda function, so you'll need to create a topic in SNS and subscribe this function to it.

Good luck!